# Insertion Sort: What am I doing Wrong?

Tags: c++, insertion-sort

I am trying to do an insertion sort. The song is a simple structure containing an Artist and Title property. I call the CompareTitle(Song& s1, Song& s2) which returns true if the song title of the first song is before the second song's title. The sort condition seems to work fine when the swapping portion of the code is commented out. When not, I get this error. Im not sure how to approach it:

> playlist.cc:192:22: error: object of type 'Song' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted
>                   *itr = j;

```
//do insertion sort
for(auto itr = newSongList.begin(); itr != newSongList.end(); ++itr)
{

    for(auto jtr=itr; jtr != newSongList.begin(); --jtr){
        cout << itr->GetTitle() << " " << jtr->GetTitle() << endl;
        // if s1 is not before s2 then swap them
        if(!Song::CompareTitle(*itr, *jtr)){
            cout << "Swap True (" << itr->GetTitle() << "," << jtr->GetTitle() << " )"<< endl;
            Song i = Song(itr->GetTitle(),itr->GetArtist());
            Song j = Song(jtr->GetTitle(), jtr->GetArtist());

            *itr = j;
            *jtr = i;

            cout << "Swap After (" << jtr->GetTitle() << "," << itr->GetTitle() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the structure of the song and playlist:

```
#ifndef PLAYLIST_H
#define PLAYLIST_H

#include <functional>   // For std::function
#include <string>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

extern void SongCallback();

class Song {
  public:
    explicit Song(const string& title, const string& artist,
        const function<void()> = &SongCallback);
        const string& GetTitle() const;
        const string& GetArtist() const;
        bool operator==(const Song& s) const;
        bool operator()(const Song& s) const;

        static bool CompareTitle(const Song& s1, const Song& s2);
        static bool CompareArtistTitle(const Song& s1, const Song& s2);

private:
    const string title_;
    const string artist_;
    const function<void()> callback_;
};

class Playlist {
public:
    explicit Playlist() {}
    void AddSong(const string& title, const string& artist);
    unsigned int RemoveSongs(const string& title, const string& artist);
    list<Song> PlaylistSortedByTitle() const;
    list<Song> PlaylistSortedByArtistTitle() const;
    unsigned int NumSongs() const;
    unsigned int NumSongs(const string& artist) const;

private:
    list<Song> songs_;
};

#endif // PLAYLIST_H
```

Comment: We don't know what type newSongList is, but inserts invalidate all iterators on a std::vector.

Comment: @FBergo, sorry newSongList is list<Song>. Songs are populated by pushing a Song with a constructor Song(string title, string artist). Ive added the method as well in my edit.

Comment: Your "swap" code inserts 2 elements and removes none. Consider `std::swap(*itr, *jtr);` instead.

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: @FBergo I unfortunately cannot use that as all my methods are const. It will complain about it.

Comment: @FeiXiang yes I have narrowed it down to the swapping. I cant swap as previously suggested because I get the error 'error: object of type 'Song' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted"

Comment: By "all my methods are const", do you mean including your sort function? How is the function supposed to sort stuff if it can't modify the object? Could we see the `Song` class? It sounds like you didn't create a copy assignment operator when you needed one. Please provide code that we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @FeiXiang that is correct. I would assume that if I made a copy of the playlist (newSongList) and sort from there and return that new list, it would be fine. I also updated the code to show the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that every time you should be swapping iterator the two elements, you are instead adding elements to the container before both `itr` and `jtr`.

```
for(auto itr = newSongList.begin(); itr != newSongList.end(); ++itr)
{

    for(auto jtr=itr; jtr != newSongList.begin(); --jtr){
        cout << itr->GetTitle() << " " << jtr->GetTitle() << endl;
        // if s1 is not before s2 then swap them
        if(!Song::CompareTitle(*itr, *jtr)){
            swap(*itr, *jtr);
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can either use `std::swap` as the swap function, or write your own function to switch the titles and artists of the songs, along with any other members that may be added to them. `std::iter_swap` could also be used as an alternative.

[`std::swap` on CPP reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)

[`std::iter_swap` on CPP reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap)

Comment: I cannot use std::swap or std::iter_swap as all my methods are const.

Comment: I wish that had been specified in the question earlier. I feel that I answered the question as originally stated, but recent edits have introduced additional complications.

Comment: Without a method being Const this is correct. Because my original question did not specify this, I will select this as the appropriate answer as it does answer my question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you have *const* `title_` and `artist_` params, you can't assign and overwrite these using `assignment operator`.

The compiler will also not generate `assignment operator`. Since the purpose of an `assignment operator` is to alter members after construction, it doesn't make sense to generate an implicit `assignment operator` when one of the member can never be altered. The compiler refuses to try and guess what you want it to do and forces you to provide your own `assignment operator` with the semantics you want.

I think instead, what you can do is manipulate the list entries using [list::insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/insert/) and [list::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase/) methods, like I've shown below to achieve your desired result.

```
for(auto itr = newSongList.begin(); itr != newSongList.end(); ++itr)
{

    for(auto jtr=itr; jtr != newSongList.begin(); --jtr){
        cout << itr->GetTitle() << " " << jtr->GetTitle() << endl;
        // if s1 is not before s2 then swap them
        if(!Song::CompareTitle(*itr, *jtr)){
            cout << "Swap True (" << itr->GetTitle() << "," << jtr->GetTitle() << " )"<< endl;
            Song i = Song(itr->GetTitle(),itr->GetArtist());
            Song j = Song(jtr->GetTitle(), jtr->GetArtist());

            newSongList.insert(itr, j); // extend list by inserting j song before itr song
            newSongList.erase(itr);     // itr is still pointing to original song
            newSongList.insert(jtr, i); // extend list by inserting i song before jtr song
            newSongList.erase(jtr);     // jtr is still pointing to original song

            cout << "Swap After (" << jtr->GetTitle() << "," << itr->GetTitle() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```